# Blenderkit Deamon not running

Tags: add-on

I installed Blenderkit Addon into my Blender version 3.4...But unfortunately it shows "daemon not running" and nothing can be downloaded .It shows Thumbnail not found . What Should I do to make the addon work?

Comment: That's a third party addon, not part of Blender, so you should start by reading the addon's [preferences](https://github.com/BlenderKit/blenderkit/wiki/BlenderKit-Preferences) setup and [troubleshooting guide](https://www.blenderkit.com/docs/add-on-troubleshooting/)